# Create Google Calendar event from Gmail message without adding recipients to Guests list?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

Is it possible to change the default behavior of the Gmail "Creat event" button? Currently, if I click the "Creat event" menu button, a new tab opens to the Google Calendar "event edit" (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit) page.
[image: Create event button]
All of the `To:` and `Cc:` recipients on the original message are automatically added to the "Guests" list and receive an event invitation if I forget to remove them before saving the event. Is there a way to set the Gmail default to not add the recipients of the original email to "Guests"? Alternatively, is there a way to set the Google Calendar default to not send an invitation to the "Guests"? Thanks!
[image: Guests section]

Comment: Using the "Create event" button imports some of the information from the email. Maybe not enough to be worth trouble...

Comment: I have tried clicking on the "Create event" button. It didn't work because it adds every recipient of the original email as a "Guest" on the new calendar event.